# A simple identity about ordered fields

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory, order-theory

Suppose I have a set of $N$ real numbers $\{x_i\}$ and I have in general, for each $i$, that $x_i^2\leq x_i$. Suppose also that I have that $\sum_i x_i^2 = \sum_i x_i$. I want to show that $x_i$ = $x_i^2$ for each $i$.  How would I go about doing that rigorously (it's intuitively clear me)? I know it's going to be something so simple (do I maybe have to use a multinomial expansion?.

This is not a homework question. This came up as part of a proof in Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development*.

Comment: The identity of $x_i^2$ isn't important to the essential question—it can be replaced by $y_i$ and it's the same phenomenon. Moreover, one can define $z_i=x_i-x_i^2$ and simplify the question even more: if $z_i\ge0$ for all $i$ and $\sum_i z_i=0$, is $z_i=0$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there were an index $j$ with $x_j^2 < x_j$. Then we would have
$$x_j-x_j^2 >0$$
and $x_i-x_i^2 \ge 0$ for all other indices. Hence
$$0 = \sum_i \left ( x_i - x_i^2 \right ) \ge (x_j-x_j^2) >0,$$
which is a contradiction. Hence $x_i = x_i^2$ for all indices $i$.

Comment: Very nice and clean, thank you. I'm mortified I couldn't get it. I will accept when SE lets me.